# Powershell: Replacing in text file - knowing that a replace was made

Tags: powershell

I have the following code in powershell:

```
foreach ($file in $Files)
  {            
     (Get-Content $file.PSPath) | 
      Foreach-Object {$_ -replace [regex]::escape($find), $repl} | 
      Set-Content $file.PSPath
  }
```

It searches a bunch of files and makes replacements and works fine. I need to make a copy of the file before modifying it by copying it somewhere. What I don't know is how to know if a replacement was made.

My question is how do you know if it made a replacement? Do I have to do a search separately (like substring)?  Obviously, I only want to make 1 backup regardless of how many lines are changed in the file. I'm not using wildcards/regex expressions if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-match` operator to perform a match test. Then if the result is true, perform the operations you want, such as backing up the file e.g.:

```
$esc_find = [regex]::escape($find)
$content = $file | Get-Content
if ($content -match $esc_find) {
    Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination ([IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($file, 'bak')
    $content -replace $esc_find | Set-Content -Path $file.FullName
}
```